# 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'days' error while using timedelta

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, celery

Here I am writing property method to display the remaining leave days and total leave days.The total leave days are working fine but `def leave_remaining_days(self)` this is not working.
I go this error

> 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'days'

Here the problem is while returning the no.of days `return leave_remaining.days` but when i return `return leave_remaining` just then it works.

How can I calculate the remaining leave days here ?

Only if `leave.is_accepted` True then i want to calculate remaining days.

**I want to decrease days `1` to the `end_day` by each day until**

**`datetime.date.today() == self.end_day`.**

EDIT: For this I used celery but this is also not working.Initially to check whether it works or not I set minutes=1 in the periodic task  but it doesn't works.

models.py

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff')
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    msg = models.TextField()
    start_day = models.DateField()
    end_day = models.DateField()
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_rejected = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def leave_days(self):
        diff = self.end_day - self.start_day
        return diff.days

    @property
    def leave_remaining_days(self):
        if self.is_accepted and not datetime.date.today() > self.end_day:
            leave_remaining = self.end_day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            return leave_remaining.days

#changes
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
@property
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=1))
def leave_remaining_day(self):
    if self.is_accepted and not datetime.date.today() > self.end_day:
        leave_remaining = self.leave_days - 1
        return leave_remaining
```

Comment: It is a `date` not a `timedelta`...

Comment: how can i decrease date by day `1` then @WillemVanOnsem ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get this error is because subtracting a `timedelta` from a `date` results in a `date`.

A `date` has no `days` attribute (which you can check by creating one and calling `dir(...)` on it or checking the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date)).

On a sidenote, if you want `leave_remaining_days` to return how many days are left until the `Leave` is up, then you should do something like:

```
@property
    def leave_remaining_days(self):
        if self.is_accepted and not datetime.date.today() > self.end_day:
            delta = self.end_day - datetime.date.today()
            return delta.days
```

Since you are storing the `start_day` and `end_day` I'm not sure you need to decrease anything each day. You could perhaps check the property I've written above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then in your code:

```
leave_remaining = self.end_day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
return leave_remaining.days
```

`leave_remaining` is a `datetime.date` that is 1 day prior to `self.end_day`, which I think is what you want; just return the date directly like this:

```
return leave_remaining
```

Comment: I wanted to return days .returning date was working fine.Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

I think most obvious answer would be to define your `leave_remaining_days` prop like this:

```
@property
def leave_remaining_days(self):
    if self.is_accepted:
        return self.leave_days - 1
```

isn't it?

Comment: with this logic it is decreasing days by `1` only once.But I want to decrease `1` by each day.

Comment: for the task you are describing, django does not provide built-in functionality, you should use cron job, or celery to run tasks periodically (once a day in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
@property
def leave_remaining_days(self):
    if self.is_accepted and not datetime.date.today() > self.end_day:
        leave_remaining = self.end_day - datetime.date.today()
        return leave_remaining.days
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall work:

```
def leave_remaining_days(self):
            if self.is_accepted and not datetime.date.today() > self.end_day:
                leave_remaining = self.end_day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                return leave_remaining.day
```

*leave_remaining.**day** will give you the remaining leave days*